# How can i replace/remove an string in a result of statistical model?

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a file included the result of a gls model (model1). How can I replace all elements of "DummyTime" as "Time"/remove "Dummy" in front of "Time" in my saved model. I've tried many ways as follows but they are not working.

```
library (stringr)
model_recode <- str_remove(model1, "[Dummy]")
model_recode <- replace(model1, function (x) if (x == 'DummyTime')'Time' else x)
```

Any help you could provide for this question would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Did you take a look at the str_replace function. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.3.1/topics/str_replace